# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in. how to fix it?

Tags: php

How to fix it?

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\SPP2\petugas\admin\kelas\id_kelas.php on line
> 12

This is the code:

```
$nilaikode = substr($jumlah_data[0], 1);
```

Comment: And what is `$jumlah_data`?  Is it an `int`?  If so, what do you expect `$jumlah_data[0]` to do and why?

Comment: The message is telling you that $jumlah_data is an integer (i.e. a number). Therefore, trying to access an item within it, as if it's an array, does not make much sense. It's unclear what you were trying to achieve with this code, or whether you expect that variable to be an int or not. We are lacking a lot of context.

Answer (score 1):

As others in the comments have noted, the value of `$jumlah_data` in this case is an integer, but it's being used as an array.

You'll likely want to trace back to where `$jumlah_data` is set and use something like `var_dump($jumlah_data)` to see what the value is and determine if it's what you expect.

Then either fix the way the variable is set so it is an array, or modify your code so that it treats the value as an integer - e.g.

```
$nilaikode = substr($jumlah_data, 1);
```